# Apply a shared Embedding layer on a set of documents in keras

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, embedding

I am trying to create a model in which I want to predict the order of a certain set of documents given a certain query. My idea was basically to use a shared embedding layer for both the query and the documents, then merge the two "branches" using a cosine similarity between each document and the query (using a custom lambda). The loss function would then compute the difference between the expected position and the predicted similarity.

My question is: Is there a way to create Embeddings for a set of textual features (provided that they have the same length)?

I can properly transform my query in a "doc2vec-like embedding" by applying Embedding + Convolution1D + GlobalMaxPooling1D, but I had no luck using the same strategy on the sets of documents (and Reshaping + 2D convolutions don't really make sense to me given that I am working with textual data).

Note that a constraint I have is that I need to use the same Embedding layer for both my query and the set of documents (I am using the Keras' functional apis to do so).

[EDIT, adding sample code]

```
Q = Input(shape=(5, ))    # each query is made of 5 words
T = Input(shape=(50, 50)) # each search result is made of 50 words and 50 docs

emb = Embedding(
    max_val,
    embedding_dims,
    dropout=embedding_dropout
)

left = emb(Q)
left = Convolution1D(nb_filter=5,
                     filter_length=5,
                     border_mode='valid',
                     activation='relu',
                     subsample_length=1)(left)
left = GlobalMaxPooling1D()(left)

print(left)
right = emb(T)   # <-- this is my problem, I don't really know what to do/apply here

def merger(vests):
    x, y = vests
    x = K.l2_normalize(x, axis=0)             # Normalize rows
    y = K.l2_normalize(y, axis=-1)            # Normalize the vector
    return tf.matmul(x, y)  # obviously throws an error because of mismatching matrix ranks

def cos_dist_output_shape(shapes):
    shape1, shape2 = shapes
    return (50, 1)

merger_f = Lambda(merger)

predictions = merge([left, right], output_shape=cos_dist_output_shape, mode=merger_f)

model = Model(input=[Q, T], output=predictions)

def custom_objective(y_true, y_pred):
    ordered_output = tf.cast(tf.nn.top_k(y_pred)[1], tf.float32)  # returns the indices of the top values
    return K.mean(K.square(ordered_output - y_true), axis=-1)

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=custom_objective)
```

**[SOLUTION]** thanks to Nassim Ben, use `TimeDistributed` like this to apply recurrently a Layer to all the dimensions of a layer like this:

```
right = TimeDistributed(emb)(T)
right = TimeDistributed(Convolution1D(nb_filter=5,
                        filter_length=5,
                        border_mode='valid',
                        activation='relu',
                        subsample_length=1)(right)
right = TimeDistributed(GlobalMaxPooling1D())(right)
```

Comment: Do you have some code to share? What you have tried so far for example :)

Comment: yes of course :) sorry for not adding it from the beginning @NassimBen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright. If I understand correctly the situation, you have 50 text snippets of length 50 that you want to embed.

After doing the word embeddings, you find yourself with a Tensor T of shape (50,50,emb_size). 
Whay I would do is to use a LSTM layer in a TimeDistributed wrapper. Adding those lines after `emb(T)` :

```
right = TimeDistributed(LSTM(5))(right)
```

This will apply the same LSTM to each of the 50 documents and output a final state of length 5 at the end of each document processing. The shape of right after this step is (50,5). You have embedded each document in a length 5 vector. 
The advantage of TimeDistributed is that the LSTM applied to each document will share the same weights so your documents will be 'treated' the same way. You can find documentation about LSTM [here](https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/#lstm) and about TimeDistributed [here](https://keras.io/layers/wrappers/).

I hope this helps a bit.

Comment: thanks, much appreciated. My only issue here is to try to understand why I would need an LSTM in this case, it literally puzzles me. I will try it :) thanks for the help

Comment: The lstm takes a sequence of vectors as input (2D arrays) and encode them by "reading" the vectors one by one. It updates a hidden state every times it takes a vector in and outputs the last state. LSTM are therefore a "natural" way to encode text as text is a sequence of word vectors (word embeddings).  Does that make sense?

Comment: makes sense in general, there is not a lot of structure in my results so I will test also timedistributed conv1d. btw the line you posted throws an error `IndexError: tuple index out of range` at line 702 of keras/layers/recurrent.py (`self.input_dim = input_shape[2]` in `def build..`) and adding input_shape doesn't fix it

Comment: nvm, I also needed to "timedistribute" the Embedding layer, this solves it

Comment: oh yes indeed. sorry I didn't see that issue. Another possibility is to reshape your input to a (50*50,) tensor, embed those words, which will output a (50*50,emb_size) tensor which you reshape again into (50,50,emb_size). Both ways are good :) So problem solved?

Comment: yes! thanks a lot for pointing me to TimeDistributed. (adding my final solution for reference to the answer)